# Attach event handler and each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the `li` I got a new `li` created. However clicking I want the same event on the new list items so I used:

```
$('ul').on( 'click', $this, function(){
```

But now the content is duplicated!

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $('ul').on( 'click', $this, function(){
            $('ul').append('<li>new</li>');
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/24cnwmqv/1/

I just want when you click on the existing or new list items you got 1 new created list item. Thank you.

Comment: remove the `$('li').each(function(){` part.

Comment: not sure if this is clear enough, I personally can't tell what you're asking? the title and description doesn't match firstly and then the description itself loses me :s

Comment: I need each to get the index of the li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're duplicating `click` event handlers in the `each` loop - remove that. Then use `li` as the selector instead of the `$li` reference:

```js
(function() {
  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('ul').append('<li>new</li>');
    
    var index = $(this).index();
    console.log(index);
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
li {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

You may also want to consider changing the logic to only append to the parent `ul` instead of all in the current DOM:

```
$(this).closest('ul').append('<li>new</li>');
```

Comment: I need each to get the index of the li

Comment: You can still do that using the method I showed above using `index()`. I edited the answer to show you

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
$('ul').on( 'click', 'li', function(){
  $('ul').append('<li>new</li>');
});
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24cnwmqv/3/).

Comment: I need each to get the index of the li